# Reduce memory consumption in development

Tags: clojure

When I'm developing my project I have 3+ jvm instances running.

- $ lein garden auto
- $ lein cljsbuild auto
- $ lein datomic start
- cider repl
- cider brepl

With firefox open for a few days I get pretty close to maxing out my 8gb of ram. How can I reduce memory consumption?

Comment: `lein trampoline` can help here (depending your workflow). good article on the topic: http://www.flyingmachinestudios.com/programming/lein-trampoline/

Comment: Just trampolining cut memory usage by nearly 2gb for me.

Answer (score 3):

while invoking the JVM, you could set the maximum size to be used

e.g -Xmx1024m -Xms1024m would use only 1GB of ram

Hope it helps
regards